# query for updating two table of a database using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

i need to update two table at a time using MySQL and PHP.I am explaining my code below.

> update.php:

```
<?php
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$dept_list=$request->dept_name;
$hod_name=$request->hod_name;
$email=$request->email;
$password=$request->password;
$hod_id=$request->hod_id;
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'Oditek123@');
mysql_select_db('go_fasto', $con);
$qry = "UPDATE db_deptHead SET dept_list='$dept_list', hod_name='$hod_name', emailid='$email' password='$password' WHERE hod_id='$hod_id'";
$qry_res = mysql_query($qry);
if($qry_res){
    echo "HOD data updated successfully";
}else{
    echo "HOD data could not updated";
}
?>
```

Here i am updating one table `i.e-db_deptHead` .i need to update another table(`db_Admin`) with field name `email_id and password` with same value.As email and password values are always same so i need to update both table.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with a multi-table update, as described in the documentation.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html

```
UPDATE Table_One a INNER JOIN Table_Two b ON (a.col1 = b.col1)
SET
  a.win = a.win+1, a.streak = a.streak+1, a.score = a.score+200,
  b.win = b.win+1, b.streak = b.streak+1, b.score = b.score+200 
WHERE a.userid = 1 AND a.lid = 1 AND b.userid = 1
```

Note: Multi-table doesn't support LIMIT, so this could cause more grief depending on the details.

Stored procedures or transactions may be a nicer solution.